# ORDER BY not working in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
while ($categories = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {
$item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zw_".$categories['Category']."s WHERE ItemId = '".$categories['Id']."' ORDER BY Level");
    $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_result);
    echo $item['Level'];
```

The output of this is

```
15 
35
55
75
95
115
135
150
15
27
48
68
83
11
40
62
80
95
110
125
```

I cant really find a pattern here. I want it to go from the lowest number to highest number, which `ORDER BY` is supposed to do, right? `Level` is always `INT` and this is inside a `while` loop.

Comment: the code you provided is not enough for a correct evaluation .. please show more code ..

Comment: It seems you are ruining your query inside a loop and you see low to high every time your ItemId is changed. Like after 150 you start for a new itemId and so on

Comment: @user3360140 That's probably it. As I said it's inside a `while` loop.

Comment: @FaabianKruse please show us more codes. If you want to simply go from lowest to highest you will probably have to get rid of the ItemId

Comment: @scaisEdge is right, we're missing some important information on what you are trying to achieve. Please be more abundant in your description and code. For example, why you want to do a query inside a while loop (=recipe for disaster if done wrong)...

Comment: @Raphioly-San because it will output multiple xmls with different values, I don't know how I am supposed to do that without a while loop.

Comment: Why not use a (inner) join between tables?

Comment: @FaabianKruse are you sure thats your code? from your output it seems you have something like, ` while ($categories = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {
        $item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zw_".$categories['Category']."s WHERE ItemId = '".$categories['Id']."' ORDER BY Level");
        while ($item = mysql_fetch_array($item_result)) {
            echo $item['Level']."\n";    
        }
    
    }`

Comment: @user3360140 No, it's directly copied.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
while ($categories = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {
$item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zw_".$categories['Category']."s WHERE ItemId = '".$categories['Id']."' ORDER BY Level ASC");
 $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_result);
 echo $item['Level'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try iterate over the result of the inner  query .. eg:

```
while ($categories = mysql_fetch_array($category_result)) {
    $item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zw_".$categories['Category']."s WHERE ItemId = '".$categories['Id']."' ORDER BY Level");
    wwhile($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_result)) {

            echo 'Category : ' . $categories['Id'] . ' Level : ' . $item['Level'];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are constructing the table name dynamically, using data you have read from some other table (or maybe elsewhere).  Hence, you want records from a collection of separate tables, and then to sort the complete set.

Perhaps you could build your SQL to create a "UNION" for each unique table, so the query runs only once and does its sorting on the entire result set.  Possibly, a union clause *(OK, the first clause is not introduced with "UNION")!)* for each ($categories['Category'], $categories['Id']) combination will be too much for your RDBMS to handle.  So, you could stick to one clause per $categories['Category'] and build all the associated  $categories['Id']s into an "IN" condition.

Worth considering whether it's better to stick with what you have, and write some code to sort the results you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

The field in database is numeric ? Try to specify the type of sort,... order by Level asc for example.

Checkout http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html